# Stopped httpd is starting alone

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, vps, httpd

I'm using an Argentinian VPS at Dattatec. Well so far this days was working great. Suddenly, we started to have a lot of httpd processes, when there were not new / a lot of new customers coming to the site, but it only slowed down the VPS.

Plus when I was shutting down httpd process, they were starting back alone. Whats going on?

Comment: What exactly are you asking in this question?

Answer (score 0):

When I see lots of abnormal http processes, I usually use the following command to check what those processes are doing:

1. Use netstat to find whether all the connections are from one IP or not. You may temporarily block that IP if it's hot-linking or attacking your server or even your server got hacked.

   netstat -na|less
2. Find which script that all the http processes are calling

   top -c

Maybe there's other practices, but we need to know what's happening on the server.